# Magento 2 receiving email from www-data@ip-x-x-x-x.eu-west-1.compute.internal instead of website name

Tags: magento2, email, aws

We are using AWS as a hosting company with magento 2.
Magento 2 welcome email,order email etc... 
customer receiving email from www-data@ip-x-x-x-x.eu-west-1.compute.internal instead of "Website name".
how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Stores->Settings->Configuration.
```

**In the panel on the left under** `General->Store Email Addresses.`

[image]

**You Can Set Sender Name Here**

Comment: yes i already set sender name and email like this
store name - "owner"
sender email - "xyz@xyz.com"

Comment: check any custom extension for email sending ??

Comment: there is no custom extension installed